# Character Recognition of Villager Moving to Another Town

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I know that villagers that move from a friend's town will retain "memories" of their old town for a while and that they stop mentioning the old town after a while. However, during this time period, if a player from that old town visits and talks to that villager, is there any recognition? Or is the response the same as for any other character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend visited my town, and when speaking to one of my villagers who had moved from his town, they knew exactly who he was and where he was from. This had been a few weeks after that had moved away from his town in the first place.

Comment: Don't other villagers also know what town you are from? Did that particular villager have a different reaction?

Comment: Other villagers who the player hasn't met treat them like a new person, with an introductory greeting, where they discover the player's name and where they're from. Villagers that are visited after they move away already recognize the player as the mayor/villager of the town they used to live in.